# Comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, nasm

I am programming in c and i compiled a c code to assembly code but when i re-compile the code with the NASM assembler , it is giving me a error

Expected comma , colon , decorator or end of line expected after operand . This occurs in 
 line number 6 , line number 7 and 8 . Please help me with this .

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, -16
sub     esp, 16
call    ___main ;
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+12], 753664
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+12]
mov     BYTE PTR [eax], 65
leave
ret
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you remove the semicolon after the statement with the call of main do the errors occur? Also are white spaces allowed in statement for example move byte ptr[eax],   65? Try to remove the white spaces before 65.

Comment: How did you compile this with `gcc`?  `gcc -S -masm=intel -o your.asm your.c`?

Comment: Yeah i compiled like that way David C.Rankin had shown !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Syntactically, using NASM, there is no `PTR` keyword. Removing those allows the code to compile up to the undefined `___main`. For example:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, -16
sub     esp, 16
call    ___main:     ; semi-colon starts comment (should be colon)
mov     DWORD [esp+12], 753664
mov     eax, DWORD [esp+12]
mov     BYTE [eax], 65
leave
ret
```

Then compiling with:

```
$ nasm -felf -o asm_recompile.o asm_recompile.asm
```

The only **error** returned is:

```
asm_recompile.asm:5: error: symbol `___main' undefined
```

Generally, NASM assembly programs require:

```
section .text
    global _start

    _start:
```

**Note:** Just because you compile to assembly with `gcc`, do not expect to be able to simply compile the code back to a working `elf` executable using NASM. `gcc` by default generates `AT&T` syntax that is incompatible with NASM. Even telling `gcc` to output assembly using the -masm=intel option to produce intel format assembly will not compile as-is in NASM. `gcc` uses `as` as the assembler. You will have varying luck using `as` as well, due to the myriad of compiler scripts and options `gcc` uses by default. The best examination of the process you can get with `gcc` is to compile your c program to executable using the `-v, --verbose` option. That will show all of the compiler commands `gcc` uses to generate the assembly associated with the c code.

Comment: `call    ___main:` is a syntax error, even if you had done `extern ___main`.  semi-colon `;` is the comment character, not `:` colon.  And you don't use `:` on symbol names you're mentioning, only when using a label to define them.  `error: invalid combination of opcode and operands` because the only syntax for a `call` that includes a `:` is a far call to a `seg:off` address, and `main` isn't a segment, and there's no offset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the errors occured due to white spaces after commas. Try to change for example statement

```
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+12], 753664
```

to

```
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+12],753664
```

Comment: This syntactic adjustment fixed the error in my case.